# Add Square Brackets Around JSON result WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following WebAPI action which returns a single value

```
    public User Get(int id)
    {

        return new User{ Name = "Chris"};
    }
```

This generates the following JSON value

```
{"Name":"Chris"}
```

However, I need the result to have [] around the JSON result like so

```
[{"Name":"Chris"}]
```

I'm aware that returning multiple results will generate the square brackets but sometimes I will only be returning one.

Is there a way I can tell WebAPI to add the square brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out (It's been a long day!).

Just need to return a collection with a single item.

```
    public IEnumerable<User> Get(int id)
    {

        var users = new List<User>();

        users.Add(new User{ Name = "Chris"});

        return users;
    }
```